# Drop a level in pandas dataframe header

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe looks like:

[image]

Can I transform this into a simple single line header, like:

```
userId  (no genres listed)  Action  Adventure  Animation
```

and also give it an index?

EDIT: `reset_index` works only partially:

[image]

My index is now named 'genre'. If I use `df.index.rename = ['index']`, it puts it on a second row again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use df.reset_index() method available in pandas. 
Refer to the link here:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html

Comment: reset index only solves part of the problem, genre is now my new index and I lost my userId column

Comment: can you provide me the file from which you are creating the dataframe?